# Spring Boot REST Hibernate - Get all the cities of a country

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

With this code:

**City.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 250)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryId", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Country country;

    // Getters and Setters
    ...
}
```

**Country.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 150)
    private String name;

    // Getters and Setters
    ...
}
```

**CityRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {
}
```

**CountryRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> {
}
```

I need Get all the cities of a country, with this code I get all cities of database:

**CityController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/cities")
public Page<City> getAllCities(Pageable pageable) {
    return cityRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

But, for get all cities of a country? How would it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access the city from the association of country.  Thus,

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

List<City> findByCountryName(String name);
Page<City> findByCountryName(String name, Pageable pageable);
List<City> findByCountryId(long id);

}
```

This will access the country object and find by name of the country. This is the **elegant way** and power of Spring data. No custom queries or named queries required. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sole requirement is to get all cities of a country, I would invert the relationship you currently have for city->country.

Having a OneToMany relationship from country to city, would allow you first find a country of interest, then simply ask that Country for all the cities associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use `findAll`. It is meant to return all. As per your requirement you should use named queries, below is an example

```
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {
    List<City> findAllCity(Pageable pageable);

}

@Entity
@NamedQuery(
    name = City.findAllCity, query = "select * from city where country= ?"
)
public class City{
    public static final String FIND_ALL_CUSTOM = "City.findAllCity";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the below method as per the official Spring documentation.

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

    public List<City> findByCountryName(String countryName);
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Comment: Yes but this, return only a city not a list with all cities of this country, right?

Comment: @Manu, You could use `List<City>` to get list of cities.

Answer (score 1):

assuming size of cities related to a country is fixed (for any country):

so....

because you need have all cities related to a specific country then simply add a bidirectional one-to-many and many-to-one relation between city and country entities 
so you can change country as below :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
public class Country extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    @Size(min = 3, max = 150)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "country",nullable = false)
    private Set<City> cities ;

    // Getters and Setters
...
}
```

but if size of citeis is not fixed  and it is  a large list (for performance reasons) you should try spring data methods like this :

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

    Page<City> findByCountry(Country country, Pageable pageable);
}
```