# Spring Boot REST Hibernate - Get all the cities of a state

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have a database with following tables -

[My State Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB15p.png)
with columns - **id** and **state**

[My City Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4cLn.png)
with columns - **id**, **city** and **state_id**

And I want to get all the cities when i request get request with a particular state id to get its cities.

**State Entity Class -**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "states")
public class State {

  @Id
  private int id;
  private String state;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
  private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();

  public State() {
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getState() {
    return state;
  }

}
```

**City Entity Class -**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {

  @Id
  private long id;
  private String city;
  private int state_id;

  public City() {

  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }

  public int getState_id() {
    return state_id;
  }

}
```

How can I get this to work ?
any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211662/spring-boot-rest-hibernate-get-all-the-cities-of-a-country

Comment: And https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwbXJB7s2Kk&ab_channel=Prakash

Comment: thanx @DavidBrossard for the help! but it still gives some errors